# How do I change field value case to be 'Camel' format?

Tags: tfs

I have custom field of string type in TFS work item with allowed values: "Yes", "No", And "Probably".

```
      <FIELD reportable="dimension" type="String" name="Help Authoring"
             refname="Custom.HelpAuthoring">
        <HELPTEXT>Should 'Help Authoring' team to update own stuff</HELPTEXT>
        <ALLOWEDVALUES>
          <LISTITEM value="Yes" />
          <LISTITEM value="No" />
          <LISTITEM value="Probably" />
        </ALLOWEDVALUES>
        <DEFAULT from="value" value="No" />
      </FIELD>
```

After importing work item into TFS project the 1st symbol case of "Probably" was changed to lower case. So now it is "probably". It looks ugly. while "Yes" and "No" are still in "Camel"-format.

Q1. Why allowed field value is changed?
Q2. How to prevent that?

P.S. To have values consistent I've tried to change "Yes" and "No" to "yes" and "no" but after importing they left in 'Camel'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, once a constant like this is imported into work items for a Team Project Collection, it's there to stay. If you feel strongly about this, log a bug with Microsoft on the [Visual Studio Connect site](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx).

One possible(?) workaround is to create a global list with the values that you want, then use that for the ALLOWEDVALUES.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gl:GLOBALLISTS xmlns:gl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/workitemtracking/globallists">
  <GLOBALLIST name="Help Authoring Values">
    <LISTITEM value="Yes" />
    <LISTITEM value="No" />
    <LISTITEM value="Probably" />
  </GLOBALLIST>
</gl:GLOBALLISTS>
```

Use `witadmin importgloballist /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/collection /f:FileName` to import it.

Then in the work item type, replace your `<LISTITEM>`'s with:

```
<ALLOWEDVALUES>
  <GLOBALLIST name="Help Authoring Values" />
</ALLOWEDVALUES>
```

Comment: Don't think I will go this way. But thank you for your answer